# finding variable in list

Tags: python, list, python-3.x

I am trying to retrieve a word from a list; I am asking the user to input a word which is part of a list, I then want to find the position of the word in that list, for example,

```
list = ["a", "b", "c", "d"]
list2 = [1,2,3,4]
```

With these lists, if the user inputs "a" then the computer works out that it is the first string in the list and picks out "1" from list2, or if they inputted "c", then it finds "3". However, due to the lists expanding and shrinking regularly, I can't use:

```
if input == list[0]:
    variable = list2[0]
etc
```

I tried doing:

```
y = 0
x = 1
while x == 1:
    if input == list[y]:
        variable = list2[y]
        x = 2
    else:
        y = y + 1
```

but that didn't work, so is there anyway that this can be done? or am I being a mong and missing the obvious...

Comment: It looks like you could do with having a dictionary that stores a mapping. Also shadowing the built in name `list` is a bad idea. Also use the `break` keyword and you can get rid of the `x` variable entirely.

Comment: lists have a built-in `index` method

Answer (score 0, accepted):

### Option 1

This is probably the simplest solution:

```
>>> list1 = ["a", "b", "c", "d"]
>>> list2 = [1, 2, 3, 4]
>>>
>>> mapping = dict(zip(list1, list2))
>>>
>>> mapping['b']
2
```

BTW, to understand what happened:

```
>>> zip(list1, list2)
[('a', 1), ('b', 2), ('c', 3), ('d', 4)]
>>> dict(zip(list1, list2))
{'a': 1, 'c': 3, 'b': 2, 'd': 4}
```

### Option 2

Anyway, you asked how to get the index in the list. Use `index`:

```
>>> list1.index('c')
2
```

And then:

```
>>> list2[list1.index('c')]
3
```

---

Also... don't name your lists `list` because that way you are "hiding" the builtin `list`.

Answer (score 0):

```
list1 = ["a", "b", "c", "d"]
list2 = [1,2,3,4]

needle = "c"
for item1, item2 in zip(list1, list2):
    if item1 == needle:
        print(item2)
```

Answer (score 0):

Here's a simple version of what I think you're trying to accomplish:

```
a = ['a', 'b', 'c', 'd']
b = [1, 2, 3, 4]

ret = input("Search: ")

try:
    idx = a.index(ret)
    print(b[idx])
except ValueError:
    print("Item not found")
```

Answer (score 0):

```
list1 = ["a", "b", "c", "d"]
list2 = [1,2,3,4]
x = input()
if x in list1 :
    print list2[list1.index(x)]
else :
    print "Error"
```